# SQL Server - Update table and return the Updated rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server database which has a lot of information inside.

I want to select top 50 rows in a single query (which I did, with no problem) but then I want to update a column from false to true, so next time I select I wont select the same, my code looks like this:

```
string Command = "UPDATE HubCommands SET [Alreadytaken] = 'true' FROM (SELECT TOP 50 [CommandId],[DeviceId],[Commandtext], [HashCommand],[UserId]  FROM HubCommands) I WHERE [HubId] = '18353fe9-82fd-4ac2-a078-51c199d9072b'";

using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnection))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command, myConnection))
    {
        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

        myDataAdapter.Fill(dtResult);

        foreach (DataRow row in dtResult.Rows)
        {
            Guid CommandId, DeviceId, UserId;
            Guid.TryParse(row["CommandId"].ToString(), out CommandId);
            Guid.TryParse(row["DeviceId"].ToString(), out DeviceId);
            Guid.TryParse(row["UserId"].ToString(), out UserId);

            Console.WriteLine("CommandId" + CommandId);
        }
    }
}
```

This code does work, and it updates what I ask it to update, but I don't get nothing in the data table, its like it is always updating but not selecting.

If I do a normal select it does work and give information.

Does anyone have any idea how to update and get some data back, in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your question is:

> How can I update a table in SQL Server using C# and return the truly updated
>   rows as a DataTable ?

**First** You have multiple issues in your query.

You should use `1` and `0`, not true or false. SQL-Server has a `bit` datatype and not a `Boolean`.

**Second**, this is how you should've constructed your query:

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE
(
    [CommandId] uniqueidentifier
);

INSERT INTO @IDs
SELECT [CommandId] FROM HubCommands
WHERE [HubId] = '18353fe9-82fd-4ac2-a078-51c199d9072b' AND [Alreadytaken] = 0;

UPDATE HubCommands 
SET [Alreadytaken] = 1
WHERE CommandId IN
(
    SELECT [CommandId] FROM @IDs
);

SELECT * FROM HubCommands 
WHERE CommandId IN
(
    SELECT [CommandId] FROM @IDs 
);
```

Wrap all the above in a single string and use `SqlDataReader`. No need for an Adapter in you case (Since we're mixing commands unlike what the adapter usually does):

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Command, myConnection);
SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult.Load(dataReader);
```

**I highly advise** you to create a stored procedure accepting `HubId` as a parameter that does all the above work. It is neater and better for maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for the 0and1 information, i did not know that. but this still does not return any information to me. do you know why? thanks

Comment: @AlonM this is an update statement. Do you want to return the updated records ?

Comment: Yes. i need them so i can work with them in my code, as you can i am trying to write the information to console in this code, thanks!

Comment: @AlonM check the edited answer and the updated query. You need to seperate the Update statement then `;` then a separate select statement. The update query **NEVER** returns data !

Comment: I think that this is not good, beacuse i need to get only the one who got updated.. is that possible?

Comment: @AlonM sorry I forgot to add the TOP 50. Added.

Comment: well, thats not 100% either. what happnd if new data comes in the seccond you did the query? also, i want in the select to add that you wont take rows when alreadytaken = true, then if i updated it i wont get any. right? i ment to add "AND AlreadyTaken='false';"

Comment: @AlonM Mmmm.. Ok i'll update my answer. The query is gonna become somehow complex.

Comment: @AlonM Updated. I hope i didn't miss anything because I was unable to generate a fake environment to test it at this moment.

Comment: You create a new table for this and then drop it for each select? i am not sure you ment for it, this table is 24/7 alive, every 30 secconds selecing. still thinks its a good idea? thanks again

Comment: @AlonM There is no other way to return exactly the updated records. There is a race condition other ways, new data might be inserted at the same time. This way, you update specific IDs and return only those IDs. There is no other way as far as I know.

Comment: @AlonM It is a TempTable. You can even replace that for `@Ids` variable table, but that needs more syntax but has less impact on performance. Variable tables are very light weight.

Comment: So you cant update and select and get the data, thats what you are saying?

Comment: @AlonM In a single update statement ? No way ! Update only returns the number of affected records by the update statement (Affected and not actually updated, the value might be as the actually set value) .

Comment: So i can change the #id to a guid and then it will be okay? it will be fast? will it work? btw, a huge thanks for the help here

Comment: @AlonM Who said Guid ? You mean changing the tempTable (#IDs) to variable table (@IDs) ?

Comment: Yes, so it will not be the same everytime, beacuse the querty can come 2 in a row when the first one did not finish yet

Comment: @AlonM Ok updating the answer.

Comment: And why did you do commandid? i need to select where hubid = , not commandid, does it matter?

Comment: @AlonM Updated. Because it is the primary key of the table, I already got those `IDs` using `where hubid=....`  The answer now uses variable table @IDs. Please be aware that you need to change the type declared for `CommandId` from `int` to match the definition of your table `HubCommands`

Comment: Commandid is not same for each row, Hubid is the same, or userid(which is guid)

Comment: @AlonM What is the primary key for that table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118758/discussion-between-alon-m-and-user3185569).

Comment: @AlonM I forgot to mention that I highly advise you to create a *Stored procedure* to do this work instead of writing all of these hard-coded queries in your code. I added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. for now i only did that hubid is a param that i give to a function, i may move to stored procedure in the next time, thanks again for all your hard work :)

Comment: Do you need to drop a declared table?